# Read json angular depends on build or serve

Tags: json, angular

small query

i need to read JSON file when serve mode and Read JSON file from dist folder after build in angular

can you suggest a way how i can achieve

Comment: Does the information really have to be in a json file instead of a typescript file? Otherwise you can set `resolveJsonModule` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

This is why we have environment variables. You should, in your `src` folder have an `environments` folder (if not... create), one ts file for prod and one for dev (ng serve). By default the prod should look like:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

and the dev:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false
};
```

So what you simply do... wherever you need to... import the environment file where you need it... For example:

```
// insert correct path
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
```

and just do an `if` check or use ternary operator... So something like this:

```
if (environment.prod) {
  // production mode, act accordingly
} else {
  // development mode, act accordinly
}
```